# RS-485 bus multiple sensors

Tags: rs485

I will keep it short I ave been searching for an definitive answer but can't find one. I am using a RS-485 breakout board (pictured below) for a sensor connected to an arduino. I now want to add another sensor to this project so do I need another breakout board for each sensor, or can they all connect to the first one?

[RS-485 Breakout board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gAF3.jpg)

And if anyone out there has a pin out for this even better.

Answer (score 0):

if you have sensors with RS485 interface you can attach them to the bus without this board, if your sensor do not have RS485 interface you need a microcontroller and this board for each sensor. The chip on this board is a *MAX485* ( https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf ) that is basically a 485/422 transceiver without any knowledge about protocols like MODBUS or Profibus, these protocols have to be implemented by an attached microcontroller, i.e arduino

**https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/RS485-Modules** <-

the pinout of the module is on page 7 of the datasheet https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf, the differential bus lines are connected to A and B